# Multiple selects in one query in java with jdbc connector-Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I try to multiple select in java. I have two string "name" and "artist" i want to select them both in one query even if one of them is null .

I did something like that :

```
if ( !nameIsEmpty && !artisIsEmpty )
{
    rst = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM school.product_table where name=" + "'" + name + "'  and artist=" + "'" + artist + "'");
}
else if ( nameIsEmpty && !artisIsEmpty )
{
    rst = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM school.product_table where  artist=" + "'" + artist + "'");
}
else if ( !nameIsEmpty && artisIsEmpty )
{
    rst = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM school.product_table where  name=" + "'" + name + "'");
}
else
{
    productIsEmpty = true;
}
```

I think its not the best way to do this. And I hope there is a easy way to this in one query.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use OR instead of AND but OR could create a query performance issue if you have a lot of data. So Yes your code looks better where you are generating the query depending on input values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT * FROM school.product_table where name in(name.null) and artist in (name,null)

Along with matching the records with name and artist, it will also return results with name=null and artist, artist=null and name, null and null.

If you want to skip both null results try this -

SELECT * FROM school.product_table where name in(name.null) and artist in (name,null) and !(artist=null && name=null)